# Using 旨 where こと could be used a well

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, business-japanese

Often in a business setting I hear Japanese speakers using この旨 where この事 seemingly fits as well.

Like 「この旨をご連絡させて頂きます」 or 「〇〇の旨かしこまりました」

Is it just a matter of corporate speak or is there a difference in meaning?

Also, would it sound strange if used outside of formal situations?

Answer (score 2):

旨{むね} only partially substitutes for こと. It means "effect" in "I'll contact them to that effect." For telling the topic of matter, you can use 件{けん} instead.

> ご契約の旨連絡させていただきます。 *I'll let them know to the effect that you (enter into the) contract.*
>
> ご契約の件連絡させていただきます。 *I'll let them know concerning your contract.*

Both of them are only used in formal/business settings.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to edit English in your answer, but first let me understand. In the first example (契約の旨) do you mean 1) 締結により影響を報告する 2) 締結するかどうか結果を伝える; also who do you mean by "them" (その事例は連絡先はだれと考えられますか)

Comment: @macraf Oh, thank you. 契約の旨 only means 2. And since I used 連絡 without honorifics, they couldn't be in the hearer's side, must be in the speaker's or are third party. Maybe "I" is an agent of "you", or a customer liaison.

Comment: It's much more complicated than I originally thought. Let's resolve it step by step. First, I think English "to the extent of" can only be applied for "(結果/影響) という旨の ( )". But "契約の旨" is so short, I cannot grasp the nuances. Second I don't understand your choice of the third party for this example. Why would anyone announce the results of the contact decision to other party than those most related? Was it relevant?

Comment: First of all, I reviewed my answer and I found one word dropped. It's "to the effect that", sorry for a silly mistake. Does it solve your confusion? And by the "third party" I meant those who take part in neither of the speaker's or the hearer's side, not necessarily are irrelevant people but can be other stakeholders. (By the way, I don't much understand your "to the extent of" part...)

Comment: Let me reverse-translate "I'll let them know to the effect that you (enter into the) contract." Based on examples in EDICT, it means「私はあなたが締結すると言う旨の情報をその人たちに言ってきます」 I don't think this is what you really wanted to say :-)

Comment: In fact, aside from wording, that Japanese seems to paraphrase my meaning correctly... Maybe I should add that "the contract" is likely to be made between "you" and "them"?

Comment: Yes, that last remark changes a lot. Give me some time to think it over.